# Are there security issues using $.post() instead of HTML form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have just noticed a potential security flaw regarding a website that is still in development - my first complete site :). I have a sign in form for users to sign in to the website. I am using jQuery's .click() alongside the $.post() method to send data for server-side processing. However, I have just noticed that the Firebug console window is displaying the sent data. Is this a security flaw for my website or is it ok?

HTML:

```
<form id="signin-form"> 
        <h2>Sign in</h2>
        <p><input type="text" id="username" autocomplete="on" autofocus /></p>
        <p><input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="on" /></p>
        <!-- DISPLAY ERRORS -->
        <p id="error"></p>
        <input id="signin-btn" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $('#signin-btn').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("disabled").prop("disabled", true);
        $(this).attr("value", "Please wait...");

        var referrer = document.referrer;
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        $.post("./signin.php", {username: username, password: password}, function(data) {
            if(data === 'success') {
                <?php if(isset($_GET['redirect'])) {
                    echo 'top.window.location.href = "' . $_GET['redirect'] . '";';
                } else {
                    echo 'top.window.location.href = referrer;';
                }
                ?>
            } else {
                $('#signin-btn').removeClass("disabled").prop("disabled", false);
                $('#signin-btn').attr("value", "Sign in")
                $('#error').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is what I see in Firebug when I send the request:

[image]

Comment: You could use URL encode... this is mainly because you have username and password in your GET URL

Comment: Neither HTTP or AJAX form-posting have any inherent security. Choosing one over the other has *nothing* to do with security. Security is a completely separate topic. This question cannot be answered because it is based on a fundamental misconception.

Comment: What *is* a security problem is the fact that you're dumping the contents of `$_GET['redirect']` directly into the browser, and evaluating it as JavaScript. That has massive potential for abuse.

Comment: @meagar Oh thanks. I will fix that straight away. Any suggestion for achieving the same without $_GET['redirect']?

Comment: use header('location: ' . $_GET['redirect']); before any html is output, that way they can't inject into the html on your webpage

Comment: If you're going to do a pass-through redirect as @CurtisW suggests, you need to whitelist which URLs are allowed so that page doesn't get hijacked by unscrupulous link hijackers.